# How to implement nested live data?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-jetpack

**How to implement nested live data in android** : I need to pass the serverMovies to second level of Live data

### ***Is this possible ?***

```
   activityViewModel.getAllMovies().observe(this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(List<Movie> serverMovies) {
                    Log.d("",serverMovies+"");

                    activityViewModel.insertMoviesIntoLocalDatabase(serverMovies).observe(this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Movie> movies) {
                            Log.d("",movies+"");
                            /*contactArrayList.clear();
                            contactArrayList.addAll(contacts);
                            contactsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();*/

                        }
                    });
                }


     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a [Mediator Live Data](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData) that reacts to changes in the movies live data.

Something like this,

```
LiveData<List<Movies>> moviesLiveData = getAllMovies();
MediatorLiveData mediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
mediatorLiveData.addSource(moviesLiveData, value -> mediatorLiveData.setValue(value));
```

So when the value of the original live data changed the value of the mediator live data changes too, then you can observe it anyway you want.

Answer (score 2):

I could also achieve using `switchmap`:

```
Transformations.switchMap(
      activityViewModel.getAllMovies(), (x) ->
      activityViewModel.insertMoviesIntoLocalDatabase(x))
      .observe(this, movies ->
       movieAdapter.setData(new ArrayList<>(movies))
 );
```